# What's the latest conda version compatible with Google Colab

Tags: anaconda, conda, google-colaboratory, miniconda

I need to use `conda` to install some library to use with Colab. It seems that we cannot use the latest Anaconda because its Python 3.7 isn't compatable.

So what's latest compatible version for both `Anaconda` and `Miniconda`? And how to install them?

Comment: @merv I have edited it to Anaconda. Thanks!

Comment: FYI, once you get the alternate version of conda installed, you can create a separate environment to test with. This will avoid any clashes with other code you run. `!conda init` `!conda create -y -q --name test36 python=3.6`. Then you can use `%%bash` and `source activate myenv` to create a shell to run your python code from

Answer (score 3):

The latest compatible versions are

- Anaconda 5.2.0
- Miniconda 4.5.4

Here's how to install them. I use an example installing `faiss` from pytorch channel.

```py
!wget -c https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-5.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
!chmod +x Anaconda3-5.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
!bash ./Anaconda3-5.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /usr/local
# can change to another channel or package
!conda install -q -y --prefix /usr/local -c pytorch faiss-cpu
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/')
import faiss
```

For Miniconda

```py
!wget -c https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh
!chmod +x Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh
!bash ./Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /usr/local
!conda install -q -y --prefix /usr/local -c pytorch faiss-cpu
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/')
```

### update 2019-12

Someone report bug. Here's the new code to install `ujson`, as an example.

```py
!wget -c https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh
!chmod +x Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh
!bash ./Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /usr/local
!conda install -q -y --prefix /usr/local python=3.6 ujson
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/')
import ujson
```